# How to cast attention to your question?

Tags: support, specific-question

I have a [question which is two months old](https://superuser.com/questions/1016699/how-can-i-retrieve-data-from-a-sd-card-when-photorec-doesnt-work), viewed 19 times, and no answer or comment on it. Thus, I asked people I know "IRL" to help me, and no one could.

I thought I could "up" it, like on forums, but I'd have to answer it to do so, and this wouldn't be an answer.
**So is there a way to cast attention to my question, without setting a bounty on it? Is this OK to do it?**

Thanks

Comment: You have enough rep to set a bounty ...

Comment: @Tloz You should provide feedback on the answers you have received, my bounty will be wasted and in 6 days if you don't

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Editing your question will bump it, but it should be a meaningful edit. Perhaps if it hasn't been answered yet, it would benefit from some additional information. What else you've tried, more detailed description of the issue, etc. Do not post an answer just to bump it, and do not frequently make trivial edits to bump it. The occasional significant edit to genuinely improve the question is perfectly fine though and will get some more eyes on it.

You do have enough rep to start a bounty, as well.